# Chef: Http_request take response

Tags: http, chef-infra

I would like to take the http response from the following http request:

```
http_request 'init' do
  url 'http://127.0.0.1:8200/v1/sys/init'
  message ({})
  action :put
end
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't do that, resources don't have output values in general. You would use the underlying HTTP library (`Chef::HTTP`) or just use something like Faraday in your own code.

Comment: Some tiny example following the answer would help a lot.

Comment: There's a million and a half ways to use HTTP, and you gave basically no information. Fortunately the Faraday docs are full of examples: https://github.com/lostisland/faraday/

Comment: Thanks! I'll take a look.